# i need a function to append data from one table to another table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, function

i have a wordpress database with custom table `wp_new_term_relationships` i need a function that would append all the records in that table to the table `wp_term_relationships`and then it would delete all the data in the first table , something like :

```
function jr_cron_insert_jobs(){
global $wpdb, $jr_log;

$sql = $wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO wp_term_relationships select * from wp_new_term_relationships");
$wpdb->query( $sql );

 // and another sql query to delete all data from the table "wp_new_term_relationships"
}

add_action('init', 'jr_cron_insert_jobs');
```

this function is not working and has no effect to mysql database i have this warning in my error_log

Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare()

so i need some one to modify it for me

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: this function is not working i dont know why ?

Comment: I think you can't use prepare method in this case, http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: i have this warning in my error_log

Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works well if i removed the prepare statement

```
function jr_cron_insert_jobs() {
global $wpdb, $jr_log;


$sql = $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO wp_term_relationships select * from wp_new_term_relationships");
$sql2 = $wpdb->query("TRUNCATE TABLE wp_new_term_relationships");


} 

   add_action('added_term_relationship', 'jr_cron_insert_jobs');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
function jr_cron_insert_jobs(){
global $wpdb, $jr_log;

$sql = $wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO wp_term_relationships select * from  wp_new_term_relationships");
$sql->execute();

//AND FOR THE DELETE STATEMENT:

$delete = $wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM wp_new_term_relationships");
$delete->execute();    
}

add_action('init', 'jr_cron_insert_jobs');
```

PDO::exec() - Execute an SQL statement and return the number of affected rows

PDO::query() - Executes an SQL statement, returning a result set as a PDOStatement object

PDOStatement::execute() - Executes a prepared statement